# Should I make a VHD or VHDX out of a Server 2008 machine?

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2, vhd

I'm using Windows Server 2012 R2 as my hypervisor. I want to transform a physical machine running Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 to a Hyper-V guest on the 2012 machine.

Can I use the VHDX format for this? I know that VHDX is only supported on Server 2012, but I can't figure out whether this applies to the guest or host (or both).

Comment: Do you have a hypervisor that supports the VHDX format?  if you don't then the answer is sort of obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guest operating system knows nothing about what format its disk image is in. (That's a big part of being a *virtual* machine.) If you're going to make a Generation 2 VM, you have to use the VHDX format. Note that if you first make a VHD and then convert it to VHDX, it's not guaranteed that Hyper-V will be able to boot it.

If your host is Windows Server 2012 R2 and your guest supports UEFI (2008 R2 doesn't), you should use the VHDX format and Generation 2 to take advantage of all the newest features.

Further reading: [Generation 2 Virtual Machine Overview](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn282285.aspx), [Hyper-V Virtual Disk Format Overview](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831446.aspx)

Comment: Sorry to dig out an old accepted answer, but if the guest is running 2008 R2, Generation 2 is not an option AFAIK. On the other hand, VHDX is OK (and even recommended, read until the end [that](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f4dfda67-335a-410f-a18c-b0b5d598af73/vhdx-support-for-w2008r2-guest) thread).

Comment: @AntoineL Ah, you're right. The guest doesn't know about its disk format on the host, but generation does matter. I've updated my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your guest operating system is Windows Server 2008 R2, you can only deploy the virtual machine as **Generation 1** VMs which supports **VHD** as a storage format.  Generation 2 VMs only supports following guest operating systems as mentioned below,

Windows Server 2012 R2

Windows Server 2012

64-bit versions of Windows 8.1

64-bit versions of Windows 8

[Refer this Microsoft link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn282285.aspx)

In Generation 2 VM, you can use either VHD or VHDX for your storage.